# Rails Single Table Inheritance (STI): Use the same views for different models makes problems with form_for in 'new' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, single-table-inheritance

I have a `Boilerplate` model which has two descending models:

- `BoilerplateOriginal`
- `BoilerplateCopy`

While `BoilerplateOriginal`s is sort of a template that admins create, `BoilerplateCopy`s are copies of the originals that are free to edit by everyone, and they also have some more associated objects (e.g. `BoilerplateCopy belongs_to: BoilerplateOriginal`, `BoilerplateCopy belongs_to: Project` or `BoilerplateCopy has_many: Findings`, all of which `BoilerplateOriginal` doesn't).

So in my opinion, it makes sense to maintain two different model classes that share the same basic functionalities.

Because they also look quite the same, I want to use the same views for them. But under the hood, they are treated a bit different, so I also have two different controllers inheriting from a base controller.

Everything seems to work fine, except that `form_for boilerplate, as:      resource_instance_name` raises an exception `undefined method`boilerplates_path'`, but only when called as`new`action, not when called as`edit` action.

Here's what I have done so far to make it work (and everything else seems to work fine):

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :boilerplate_originals

# app/models/boilerplate.rb
class Boilerplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_partial_path
    'boilerplates/boilerplate'
  end
end

# app/models/boilerplate_original.rb
class BoilerplateOriginal < Boilerplate
end

# app/controllers/boilerplates_controller.rb
class BoilerplatesController < InheritedResources::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource

  private

  def boilerplate_params
    params.require(:boilerplate).permit(:title)
  end
end

# app/controllers/boilerplate_originals_controller.rb
class BoilerplateOriginalsController < BoilerplatesController
  defaults instance_name: 'boilerplate'
end

# app/views/boilerplates/_form.html.slim
= form_for boilerplate, as: resource_instance_name
  # ...
```

As pointed out, `new/create` works flawlessly, but `edit` doesn't. And I'm using [InheritedResources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources), by the way.

Comment: show your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: what is `resource_instance_name` ?

Comment: `resource_instance_name` is from `InheritedResources`, it's the name of the current resource (e.g. `boilerplate`). By passing it as the `:as` option, it builds a form with input names like `boilerplate_title` (and not `boilerplate_original_title`), and thus can be used for any boilerplate model.

Comment: In fact, as I want the form to be built always as `boilerplate`, I can skip `resource_instance_name ` and simply do `as: :boilerplate`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Rails is dong it correctly, you're slightly doing it wrong

the problem is:

```
resources :boilerplate_originals
```

that will just generate routes for especially boilerplate_originals. 
when using form_helpers of rails rails will lookup for a route based on the models class which is in this case "boilerplate_copy". that means its looking for a edit_boilerplate_copy_path (which isnt generated by rails)

You said that BoilerplateCopy and BoilerplateOriginal are pretty much looking the same (i guess you just copy a model, there are gems out for doing that for you...)

If you go correct STI it "should" be

```
class Boilerplate; end
class BoilerplateCopy < Boilerplate; end
class BoilerplateOriginal < Boilerplate; end
```

for that you need only a route for Boilerplate

```
resources :boilerplate
```

and of course a `boilerplate_controller`

everything is handled as a boilerplate and the form_helper will look up for a `new_boilerplate_path`, which exists, no matter if its a copy or a original.

Comment: just keep track on how your models changed. https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail or maybe that one https://github.com/amoeba-rb/amoeba

Comment: so, this is not what I need; I added some more introductory info to the thread.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, huan so. I definitely don't want a single `resources :boilerplates`, as I want two different controllers act upon them (e.g. different allowed strong parameters). I just don't understand why the `new` action tries to create a path acting upon `Boilerplate` and not upon `BoilerplateOriginal`.

Comment: if you need 2 different controller, then you need 2 different routes, for the edit/update action. resources :boilerplate_copy, only[:new, :create, :update]

Comment: Yes I will need them, this is true. Thanks for helping me. It's working now as expected, see my answer above.

Comment: yes you can do it with the override of the defaultinstanceclass but thats not really quality code. i recommend to share 1route/1controller or if you really need the control by 2 controllers let them use different routes  (you still can share the views)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

```
# app/controllers/boilerplate_originals_controller.rb
class BoilerplateOriginalsController < BoilerplatesController
  defaults instance_name: 'boilerplate' # This is wrong!
  defaults instance_name: 'boilerplate', resource_class: BoilerplateOriginal # This is right!
end
```

Now a `BoilerplateOriginal` object is passed to the `new` action, and not a `Boilerplate` object.